# Merge two tables on partly matching column

Tags: postgresql, join, pattern-matching

I have below 2 tables.

```
old_name    old_value
Tom1        100
Kate1       80
Jim1        70

new_name   new_value
Tom2       70
Kate2      100
Jim2       80
```

I want to make a new table look like

```
old_name    old_value       new_name    new_value
Tom1        100             Tom2        70
Kate1       80              Kate2       100
Jim1        70              Jim2        80
```

How to do that in Postgres?

Comment: How do the two tables relate to each other? By firstname/nickname?

Comment: I have amended the table, they are related by the name (e.g. Tom1 = Tom2)

Comment: What is the relationship between the 1 and 2 appended to the names? Are the names without the 1/2 suffix unique? For example, can there only be a Tom1 and Tom2, but no Tom3, Tom4, etc? And is the 1 suffix the only suffix in the first table, and 2 is the only suffix in the second table?

Comment: Tom1 = Tom2, there is not Tom3 or Tom4, Tom1 and Tom2 are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some pattern matching / string manipulation in the `JOIN` condition. I use [`left()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in my example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_old o
JOIN   tbl_new n ON left(n.new_name, -1)
                  = left(o.old_name, -1)
```

This assumes that all names have exactly *one* pending character (digit or no, doesn't matter).

`left(string, -1)` (with a negative length parameter) effectively trims the last letter from `string`. Should be fastest. Requires Postgres **9.1**.
In older version substitute with `substring()` or one of many other ways ...

Comment: +1 Nice use of `LEFT()`. Simple and clean.